# Android API 19 : OnBackPressed I want to close the application and show all the installed apps

Tags: android

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This is my piece of code.
I am getting error "no activity found to handle intent action_all_apps".
I can understand that I have not written any class while creating new intent.
But, I am not understanding which class to use.
Can either of you guide me in achieving my target of "closing the application and show all the installed apps".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    System.exit(0);
```

But it is advisable to handle all onBackPressed() methods in your Activites to maintain a smooth flow of youe applicatin.

Comment: Thanks dear. This is taking me to "home" screen, not to the menu screen where all the installed apps are shown. Can you throw some more light?

Comment: I could solve this problem with following code:  Intent intent = new Intent(Context, <class>);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);